# Transfer Domain settings from hosting to own server

Tags: domains, web-hosting, email, domain-transfer

At my workplace, we have a pretty messed up setup for our website, say `domain.com`, that was earlier hosted with another company, say `hostingCompany1`

At `hostingCompany1`, there are 2 control panels:

1. Domain (*has the `domain.com`, points to some IP*)
2. Hosting (*points `domain.com` and subdomains to our server, has Gmail MX records*)

We are using our own server with the settings still at the second control panel.

Which means, when someone visits our site, it resolves to:

`domain.com` > `hostingCompany1 DNS` > `hostingCompany1 Hosting` > `Our Server`

This is a pretty messed up scenario and I would like to clean it up to be more like:

`domain.com` > `hostingCompany2 DNS` > `Our Server`

1. When I finally transfer `domain.com` from `hostingCompany1` to `hostingCompany2`, how do I achieve the above scenario (i.e., remove the middle man)?
2. Do the domain settings (MX) have to be on `hostingCompany2` or our custom server?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be create child nameservers (e.g., `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com`) pointing to the IP address of your custom server.  You usually do this at your domain registrar.

Then create `A` records for `ns1.` and `ns2.` pointing to the same IP address and add that to the `hostingcompany1 DNS`.

Then, of course, you change your `domain.com` nameservers to point to `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com`.